# Clonezilla pxe boot via uefi

Tags: centos, uefi, pxe, clonezilla

I've succesfully setup Clonezilla boot on my Centos 7 PXE server legacy mode, but when I tried to get UEFI PXE working, I got stuck and it doesn't boot at all. I am using similar settings to launch it and it claims that it cannot find the file. I can't really read any log files since the computer freezes as soon as it starts to try to boot.

Config I was using in legacy mode:

```
label Clonezilla Live
menu label Clonezilla Live
kernel boot/tools/clonezilla/vmlinuz
append initrd=boot/tools/clonezilla/initrd.img boot=live union=overlay config components quiet edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noslpash noprompt noswap vga=788 ocs_repository="nfs4://10.1.45.8/home/bbox/"  fetch=http://10.1.45.8/images/clonezilla/live/filesystem.squashfs
```

And on UEFI:

```
menuentry 'Clonezilla Live' {
ip=dhcp
linuxefi uefi64/boot/tools/clonezilla/vmlinuz
initrdefi uefi64/boot/tools/clonezilla/initrd.img boot=live union=overlay config components quiet edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noslpash noprompt noswap vga=788 ocs_repository="nfs4://10.1.45.8/home/bbox/"  fetch=http://10.1.45.8/images/clonezilla/live/filesystem.squashfs}
```

However I was able to successfully boot live centos installation on both environments, so the uefi boot itself is working and there has to be something to do with Clonezilla config. Or could it be that clonezilla live images doesn't support UEFI?
[image: It stops at]
[image: And then all it shows is this.]

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using another grub loader (alternative clonezilla  version).